# Trigger Firebase build when new content is creaated in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, firebase, github, next.js

I have a static site deployed to Firebase using `next export` when new content is added from WordPress, I want to trigger the Github build or auto-trigger the Firebase build.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can set up a webhook in Wordpress. Once a new content is inserted it should invoke git build api. Refer to this for more info: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274068/how-do-i-set-up-a-webhook